# How to perform actions on successful login via OAuth2 in jhipster

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, jhipster

I want to ask how to perform an action after a successful login via OAuth2 and how to veto a login based on some preconditions. I tried to search on Google and found some links but I'm not sure how to do that on this framework. There might be some filter etc I can add but wanted to know the right place to do this.

*Note: The AuditEvent will not work for me since successful audit is called with every API call.*

Ref: http://blog.jdriven.com/2015/01/stateless-spring-security-part-3-jwt-social-authentication/

**What I need to do is:**

1. After successful login, record a few details in a table and send a notification to a queue. In addition to successful login, I also want to perform some action on successful logout which I know I can do here: AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler. However I'm not able to find a similar place for successful login.
2. Before login via OAuth2 if a certain condition is not met, then I can throw an exception and not allow that user. For example, if the user is coming from a particular IP range. Where can I add this?

Please guide me in right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter implementation

**CustomTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
public class CustomTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter extends TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter {

    public CustomTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, OAuth2RequestFactory oAuth2RequestFactory) {

        super(authenticationManager, oAuth2RequestFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException {

                /* on successful authentication do stuff here */

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
                /* before authentication check for condition if true then process to authenticate */
        if (!condition) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("condition not satisfied");
        }
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }
}
```

Inside **AuthorizationServerConfiguration** make these changes

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Inject
    private JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    /* create OAuth2RequestFactory instance */
    private OAuth2RequestFactory oAuth2RequestFactory;

    @Inject
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
        throws Exception {
        /* assign value in OAuth2RequestFactory instance */
        oAuth2RequestFactory = endpoints.getOAuth2RequestFactory();
        endpoints
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        /* register TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter with oauthServer */
        oauthServer
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
            .addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(new CustomTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager, oAuth2RequestFactory));

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getClientid())
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .authorities(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.USER)
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token", "authorization_code", "implicit")
            .secret(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getSecret())
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getAuthentication().getOauth().getTokenValidityInSeconds());
    }
}
```

Comment: I used above approach but getting error message "No client authentication found. Remember to put a filter upstream of the TokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter"  , It seems something I am missing , any suggestion on this