# How to integration 2(Or more ) jHipster Application via OAuth2?

Tags: oauth, jhipster

I have set up a application named "UserCenter" here is the .yo-rc.json

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
      "jhipsterVersion": "3.12.0",
      "baseName": "UserCenter",
      "packageName": "com.company.test.user",
      "packageFolder": "com/company/test/user",
      "serverPort": "19090",
      "authenticationType": "oauth2",
      "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
      "clusteredHttpSession": false,
      "websocket": false,
      "databaseType": "sql",
      "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
      "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
      "searchEngine": false,
      "messageBroker": false,
      "buildTool": "maven",
      "enableSocialSignIn": false,
      "useSass": true,
      "applicationType": "monolith",
      "testFrameworks": [
         "gatling"
      ],
      "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
      "enableTranslation": true,
      "nativeLanguage": "zh-cn",
      "languages": [
         "zh-cn",
         "en"
      ],
      "serviceDiscoveryType": false
    }
```

}

and another application named "MsgCenter" here is the .yo-rc.json

```
{
    "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.12.0",
    "baseName": "MsgCenter",
    "packageName": "com.company.test.msg",
    "packageFolder": "com/company/test/msg",
    "serverPort": "19002",
    "authenticationType": "session-based",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": true,
    "useSass": true,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "zh-cn",
    "languages": [
      "zh-cn",
      "en"
    ],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": false,
    "skipUserManagement": true
  }
```

}

I want to make MsgCenter to login via UserCenter Oauth2. How can I go?

Add information:
I had found this page [How to perform actions on successful login via OAuth2 in jhipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545046/how-to-perform-actions-on-successful-login-via-oauth2-in-jhipster)

I'am not sure for this.

Answer (score 1):

with your current setup, your second application, named "MsgCenter", is initially configured to have a own user management. For the moment, there is no automatically generated counter part for an oauth2 authserver for monoliths (the default option of JHipster).

How ever you can turn your MsgCenter into a oauth2 resource server by doing the following steps:

First, you change your WebSecurityConfiguration into a ResourceServerConfiguration (use `@EnableResourceServer`). There are samples how to do this if you generate a JHipster microservice with UAA scenario. But instead of JWT, you do the "normal" way via user info URI, and configure it like this

```
security:   
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: jhipsterOauth2SampleApplicationapp
      clientSecret: my-secret-token-to-change-in-production # if still default
      accessTokenUri: http://UserCenterUrl/oauth/access_token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://UserCenterUrl/dialog/oauth
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://UserCenterUrl/account
```

Refer to https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/03/sso-with-oauth2-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-v and the links following from that

In your second step, you then should remove the user management from MsgCenter, as it is no longer needed anymore.

This approach is using the authorization flow, where the resource server is retrieving the users details by a user info uri.

The other approach is to use JWT tokens. JHipster provide a full oauth2 setup with authorization and resource servers connected to each other in the [microservice UAA setup](http://jhipster.github.io/using-uaa/), which might help you as sample code to look for correct implementation.